# Currency/Date datframe merge failing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Having issues with merging two *datframes* (`xrate` and `df`) based on `currency_str` and `created_date_time`

```
display(xrate.info())

Int64Index: 1611 entries, 6 to 112
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Date        1611 non-null datetime64[ns]
PX_LAST     1611 non-null object
Currency    1611 non-null object

display(xrate.head(3))

Date       PX_LAST  Currency
2018-05-30  1       CAD
2018-05-29  1       CAD
2018-05-28  1       CAD
```

I created a new date to merge on:

```
#df['formatted_created_date_time'] = df['created_date_time'].dt.strftime('%d%m%Y')
df['formatted_created_date_time'] = df['created_date_time'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
#convert to date
#df['formatted_created_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['formatted_created_date_time'], format='%d%m%Y')
df['formatted_created_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['formatted_created_date_time'], format='%d-%m-%Y')


display(df.info())

RangeIndex: 3488 entries, 0 to 3487
Data columns (total 43 columns):
created_date_time              3488 non-null datetime64[ns]
rfq_create_date_time           3488 non-null datetime64[ns]
currency_str                   3488 non-null object

display(df.head(3))
```

[image: dataframe image]

Now the two dataframes are merged:

```
result = pd.merge(df, xrate, left_on=['currency_str', 'formatted_created_date_time'], right_on=['Currency', 'Date'], how='left')

display(result.info())

RangeIndex: 3488 entries, 0 to 3487
Data columns (total 43 columns):
created_date_time              3488 non-null datetime64[ns]
rfq_create_date_time           3488 non-null datetime64[ns]
.
.
formatted_created_date_time    3488 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

The match has failed:

```
display(result.head(3))
```

[image]

System Datetime:

[image]

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: One idea, there is no problem first row are not matched by datetimes and currency, so `left join` generate empty values? And another rows wicht matched pairs columns working nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should working nice.

But another solution is merge by `string`s:

```
df['formatted_created_date_time'] = df['created_date_time'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
xrate['Date'] = xrate['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

result = pd.merge(df, xrate, left_on=['currency_str', 'formatted_created_date_time'], 
                             right_on=['Currency', 'Date'], how='left')
```

---

Your solution should be simplify by [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)

```
df['formatted_created_date_time'] = df['created_date_time'].dt.floor('d')
xrate['Date'] = xrate['Date'].dt.floor('d')

result = pd.merge(df, xrate, left_on=['currency_str', 'formatted_created_date_time'], 
                             right_on=['Currency', 'Date'], how='left')
```

```
df['formatted_created_date_time'] = df['created_date_time'].dt.date
xrate['Date'] = xrate['Date'].dt.date

result = pd.merge(df, xrate, left_on=['currency_str', 'formatted_created_date_time'], 
                             right_on=['Currency', 'Date'], how='left')
```

Comment: No match on my solution and on the floor and Date solutions it giving the error: Getting the error AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values with all three solutions against xrate['Date'] =....

Comment: @PeterLucas - I am a bit confused, first `xrate['Date'] = xrate['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` working and then `xrate['Date'] = xrate['Date'].dt.floor('d')` failed? Both working with datetimes only. Maybe you forget delete/cooment `xrate['Date'] = xrate['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` and only add `xrate['Date'] = xrate['Date'].dt.floor('d')`

Comment: we are all good. The issue was realted to a read error in the file xrate_huf = pd.read_csv('BBG_Cross_Rates.csv', usecols=[26,27], names = ['Date', 'PX_LAST'] )[6:]. I should have viewed the entire dataframe not just the head. Both your solutions are on the money. Thanks again